# Inheritance from button in Kivy does not work

Tags: inheritance, kivy

I have learned from [the docs](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html) how inheritance worked, so I fancy my own button. Now I am doing it exactly (probably not, but seemingly so) as instructed and I get an unrelated error.

```
<btn@Button>:
    background_normal: ''

<Top>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    btn:        
        background_color: 0.1,1,0.1,.9
        on_release: root.SQLdef(1, 1)       
    btn:
        background_color: 1,0.4,0,.9
        on_release: root.SQLdef(0, 1)       
    btn:
        background_color: 1,0,0,.9
        on_release: root.SQLdef(-1,1)

<Bottom>:   
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Button:
        text: "Inchecken"
    Button:
        text: "Uitchecken"

<Container>:
    rows:2
    color: None
    Top:
    Bottom:
```

With this code I get:

> File "~\markup.kv", line 13
>        background_color: 1,0,0,.9
>                                                   ^  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

But when I change the `btn` into `Button` and put the `background_normal` in every instance of the button, it runs like a sunshine. I am lost for days and decided to ask for help. What elephant in the room am I missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first letter of a class name should be uppercase try this:

```
<Btn@Button>:
    background_normal: ''

<Top>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Btn:        
        background_color: 0.1,1,0.1,.9
        on_release: root.SQLdef(1, 1)       
    Btn:
        background_color: 1,0.4,0,.9
        on_release: root.SQLdef(0, 1)       
    Btn:
        background_color: 1,0,0,.9
        on_release: root.SQLdef(-1,1)

<Bottom>:   
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Button:
        text: "Inchecken"
    Button:
        text: "Uitchecken"

<Container>:
    rows:2
    color: None
    Top:
    Bottom:
```

Comment: Okay, so there really was an elephant in the room. Thanks!

Comment: Very interesting!!! I have seen the capitalization of class names recommended, i.e., mentioned as "should", but never as "shall" or "must". Perhaps the documentation "should" be corrected.